# What is wrong with this css targeting?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I might have been staring at the computer screen too long today and looked over something small but why can I not target these individual cells? (a1, a2, a3, etc...)

```
<div class="row-a">
    <div class="a">
        <div class="1"></div>
            sdf
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="4"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="5"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="7"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="8"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="9"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="a">
        <div class="10"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.row-a div.a div.1 {
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color:red;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tuHLE/

Comment: Your class names may be valid in HTML5, but that doesn't make them valid in CSS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't begin a class name with a digit, which is why your code is not working.

See [Which characters are valid in CSS class names/selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names).

**Edit:** Well, ok, not exactly.  Technically, you *can* begin a class name with a digit. In fact, you can use almost anything as a class name (except NUL). However, if you use a class name that begins with a digit, you will have to escape it in your CSS. For example, to select your `class="1"` div, you could do the following:

```
.row-a .a .\31 {...}
```

See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes for more information.

Comment: You (and others) were correct.  Thank you for the help.  I ended up changing the numbers to text (one, two, three, etc.)

Comment: You can also use an attribute selector, e.g. `[class="1"]{}` - it has to be quoted though